# Primes dividing sum of binomial coefficients.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Given that $p>3$ is a prime, we have $k=\lfloor \frac {2p}{3} \rfloor$ then prove or disprove that $\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{p}{i}\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$.

Its easy to see how $p$ divides each of the binomial coefficients, but I tried using maximal powers of $p$ in each coefficient but was stuck can someone help.

Comment: I mean to prove the sum is divisible by p^2 or give a counterexample that its not true.

Comment: True for $p=5, 7$, is it obvious that $p | \sum_{i=1}^k \binom p i / p$?

Comment: I dont think so. If it was then there were no problems, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure whether it helps, but by Wilson's theorem $$\frac{1}{p}\binom{p}{i} \equiv (-1)^{i-1}\overline{i} \pmod{p},$$ where $\overline{i}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse of $i$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Why do you need Wilson's theorem? Anyway, I used this to check all primes up to $p_{23000}$ and I now convert my program to a more efficient language. I will also look at all possible subsets of binomial coefficients to see if there are any further patterns.

Comment: @i9Fn Right, we don't need Wilson's theorem. It just sprang to mind upon seeing $(p-1)!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{2p}{3} \rfloor} \binom{p}{i} = 0 \mod p^2$ for $p$- primes.

$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{2p}{3} \rfloor} \binom{p}{i} = 0 \mod p^2$ imply that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{2p}{3} \rfloor} \frac{1}{p}\binom{p}{i}  =  \sum \limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{2p}{3} \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i} = 0 \mod p $ (as mentioned in the comments).

For $p=3k+1$ => $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{2k} \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i} = 1+\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2i+1}-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{2i} = \frac{1}{2} \left(H_{k-\frac{1}{2}}-H_k+\log (4)\right)$

and since $H_{2k}=\frac{1}{2}(H_k+H_{k-1/2}+\ln 4)$

we can get that

$\frac{1}{2}(H_{k-1/2}-H_k+\ln 4)-\frac{1}{2}(H_{k-1/2}+H_k+\ln 4) = -H_{2k} \mod (3k+1)$.

Which is just $-H_k = -H_{2k} \mod (3k+1)$

**Rearranging that we arrive at $H_{2k}-H_k = 0 \mod (3k+1)$ when $p=3k+1$ is prime.**

For $p=3k+2$ => $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{2k+1} \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i} = 1+\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2i+1}-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{2i}+\frac{1}{2k+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left(H_{k-\frac{1}{2}}-H_k+\log (4)\right)+\frac{1}{2k+1}$

and since $H_{2k}=\frac{1}{2}(H_k+H_{k-1/2}+\ln 4)$

we can get that

$\frac{1}{2}(H_{k-1/2}-H_k+\ln 4)-\frac{1}{2}(H_{k-1/2}+H_k+\ln 4)+\frac{1}{2k+1} = -H_{2k} \mod (3k+2)$.

Which is just $-H_k+\frac{1}{2k+1} = -H_{2k} \mod (3k+2)$

**Rearranging that we arrive at $H_{2k}-H_k+\frac{1}{2k+1} = 0 \mod (3k+2)$ when $p=3k+2$ is prime.**

**Note** : $H_k = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{i}$ is the Harmonic number and also the highlighted part,are the statements that i did not prove.

Comment: How do you define half integer harmonic number and prove these identities?

Comment: @i9Fn see the Harmonic numbers page on Wikipedia, it has a lot of useful identities that i used to reach to these equivalent statemetns

Answer (score 1):

Ahmad showed the problem is equivalent to

1. $H_{2k}-H_k \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$
2. $H_{2k}-H_k+(2k+1)^{-1}  \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

1:
$$H_{2k}-H_k \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{2k} i^{-1} - \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^{-1} \equiv \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k} i^{-1} \equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} i^{-1} + \sum_{i=\frac{3}{2}k+1}^{2k} i^{-1} \equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} i^{-1} + \sum_{i=-\frac{3}{2}k-1}^{-2k} (-i)^{-1} \equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} i^{-1} + \sum_{i=3k+1-\frac{3}{2}k-1}^{3k+1-2k} (-i)^{-1} \equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} i^{-1} + \sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} (-i)^{-1} \equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} i^{-1} + \sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} (-1)^{-1}(i)^{-1}\equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} i^{-1} + -i^{-1}
\equiv
\sum_{i=k+1}^{\frac{3}{2}k} 0
\equiv
0
\pmod p$$
The idea is that for each inverse the opposite inverse is also in the sum and therefore the sum cancelled out. You need to show $k$ is even so no inverse has no companion. If $k$ is odd, $3k+1$ is divisible by $2$ and therefore not a prime.

2:
Same idea just with odd number of terms.
$$\begin{align}
H_{2k}-H_k+(2k+1)^{-1}  \equiv \\ &
\equiv
(2k)^{-1}+(2k-1)^{-1}+\cdots+(1)^{-1} - ((k)^{-1}+(k-1)^{-1}+\cdots+(1)^{-1}) + (2k+1)^{-1} \\ &
\equiv
(2k)^{-1}+(2k-1)^{-1}+\cdots+(k+1)^{-1} +(2k+1)^{-1} \\ &
\equiv
(2k)^{-1}+(2k-1)^{-1}+\cdots+(k+1)^{-1} + (2k+1)^{-1} \\ &
\equiv
-(k+2)^{-1}+-(k+3)^{-1}+\cdots+(k+1)^{-1} + -(k+1)^{-1} \\ &
\equiv
0
\pmod p \end{align}$$
Again we need to show $k$ is always odd. If $k$ is even $3k+2$ is divisible by $2$.